# Are Storage API limited in size for Google Chrome applications?

Tags: google-chrome-app, indexeddb, web-sql, web-storage

Storage APIs (IndexedDB, WebSQL, LocalStorage) are limited in size for online web applications, is this the same for packaged Google Chrome applications ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a permission, `"unlimitedStorage"`, that unlocks *some* limitations.

There is an overview in the Apps docs: [Managing HTML5 Offline Storage](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage).

Also, note that packaged apps can't use [some of the Web Platform features](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated), namely `localStorage` and friends, as well as webSql are **excluded** (replaced respectively by `chrome.storage` and IndexedDB).

What you can use in a Chrome App:

- `chrome.storage.local`
- `chrome.storage.sync` (with quotas regardless of `"unlimitedStorage"`)
- IndexedDB
- [HTML FileSystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) for "virtual" filesystems
- `chrome.fileSystem` for access to real filesystem via user prompts
- `chrome.syncFileSystem` as a filesystem backed by Google Drive (obviously, limited)